# Flutter: cubit to cubit communication

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, bloc

I have a finance app that has wallets ( accounts ) and transactions per wallet.

Now I need to switch between wallets and change all transactions components underneath.

What currently I am doing, creating a cubit called `activeWalletCubit` and I just listen to it if it changed, and reinitiate transactions components based on that wallet, like the showing on below code.

I need to know if what I am doing is right or best practice, or is there a better way to do it?!

```dart
class TransactionsList extends StatelessWidget {
  const TransactionsList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => getIt<TransactionWatcherCubit>()
        ..initialized(
            BlocProvider.of<ActiveWalletCubit>(context).state.walletDomain),
      child: BlocListener<ActiveWalletCubit, ActiveWalletState>(
        listenWhen: (previous, current) =>
            previous.walletDomain != current.walletDomain,
        listener: (context, state) {
          BlocProvider.of<TransactionWatcherCubit>(context)
              .initialized(state.walletDomain);
        },
        child: BlocBuilder<TransactionWatcherCubit, TransactionWatcherState>(
          builder: (context, state) {
            return state.when(
              initial: () => Container(),
              loading: () => const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
              error: (_) => const Center(child: Text('error')),
              loaded: (transactions) => ListView.builder(
                itemCount: transactions.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, i) => ListTile(
                  title: Text(
                    's ${transactions[i].id} ${transactions[i].value} ${transactions[i].date}',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```